# Kibana Query Language - find numbers in a field

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am struggling with a simple query that is supposed to work based on many tutorials but cannot make it work. Havin log field

```
Request sent, method=GET, headers={}, queryParams={forceArray=[true]}, entity=null, payload length=null} playerId=102
```

I am trying to get playerId with 3 digits value. Following query fails

```
log: /playerId=[0-9]{1,3}/
```

with `KQLSyntaxError: Expected AND, OR, end of input, whitespace but "{" found. and log: /playerId=[0-9]{1,3}/`

but supposed to work according to https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-kibana-advanced-searches

This `log: /playerId=[0-9][0-9][0-9]/`returns basically everything with a single '0' character

This `log: /playerId=*/` for some mysterious reasons returns nothing.

Edit

regular elastic search lucene based query does not work either

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "log": {
        "value": "*playerId*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mapping:

```
{
  "my-index" : {
     "mappings" : {
       "log" : {
        "full_name" : "log",
          "mapping" : {
            "log" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any help appreciated

Edit

I validated my regex queries in https://regex101.com/
and they all work.

Edit 2
this works

```
"query": {
  "match": {
    "log": "playerId"
  }
}
```

this return empty hits

```
"query": {
  "regexp": {
    "log": "playerId"
  }
}
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

This is because Kibana uses [KQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html) (Kibana Query Language) by default and that doesn't support regular expressions.

You need to switch to the [Lucene Query Language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html) with the [query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) which supports the regular expression you're trying.

Just click on KQL at the right end of the search bar to change the search syntax.

Also worth noting that regular expression queries are real performance hogger. You should really parse your logs before ingesting them so you can query the playerId field independently.

In any case, if you really want to do it that way, your query is not that far off from the real thing. Here is the correct version that will work for your case:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "/.*playerId=[0-9]{3}/",
      "default_field": "log.keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that does not help either, none of the queries return anything

Comment: Can you update your question by adding your index mapping?

Comment: mapping added, regards

Comment: It doesn't look like a correct mapping. Did you copy/paste bits and pieces together?

Comment: This is the result of GET /my-index/_mapping/field/log query

Comment: My bad, I always forget that the result of that call looks pretty different than the one for the full mapping.

Comment: I can provide one for full mapping too if needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to parse the log lines prior to ingesting them so that `playerId` becomes a full fledge field that you can query on?

Comment: Most likely, but this is not something I can change since this would require rewriting log4j pattern as well as fluent bit parser pattern.
In general the query should be easy as I can mimic numbers with regexp, for instance values 10-19 are expressed as 1[0-9]{1} in any query language but for some reasons not in lucene unless I am doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work - "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }

Comment: Weird, as I recreated an index with the exact same mapping and added a document with the exact same content. That query returns one hit for me. Are you sure you're querying the `log.keyword` field?

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted the query. Basically none of the queries I tried workm but surprisingly KQL works as expected.

Comment: There's no way regular expression queries work with KQL

Comment: Let me rephrase myself - simple queries like log: playerId work, but stuff like {
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "log": "*playerId*"
    }
  }
} does not

Comment: You cannot paste a DSL query inside the search box of Kibana. You can run that query inside Dev Tools

Comment: Yes I know, I wasnt clear enough in my previous post.